# How do I parse this php server response to eliminate empty elements?

Tags: php, mysql, ios, nsarray

Ok Im getting a php server response like this:

```
[[],[],[],[{"username":"xcodeSim","PUNTOS":"5"}],[],]
```

which is expected because I am fetching data from a mySQL with this code which is a php file that receives an NSArray serialized post like this:

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:usersArray options:0 error:&error];
```

So the server does this:

```
foreach ($post_data as $value) 
{
  //CREATE QUERY
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT username, SUM(points) AS PUNTOS FROM tags WHERE username='$value' GROUP BY username");

  //EXECUTE QUERY & ADD EACH USER/POINTS DICTIONARY TO $resultado ARRAY
  $resultado = array();
  while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result)) 
  {
    $resultado[] = $obj;
  }

  //STORE RESULTS IN NEW OBJECT TO RETURN
  $arrayToReturn[] = $resultado;

}

Echo $json->encode($arrayToReturn);
```

So I have two questions:

1) How do I eliminate the internal arrays for each user-points dictionary?

2) And how do I eliminate the empty internal arrays from the master array?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're bulding a multi-level array when you don't need do. Skip the entire $arrayToReturn business:

```
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
   $arr[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```